# How can I buy development cards?

Tags: splendor

I have already bought 3 emerald development cards and I have 3 emerald tokens. I would like to buy a card which costs 3 emeralds. Do I need to pay with my tokens, or is it OK to have this with my development cards, so in the end it was for free?

Comment: I don't think this is quite a duplicate, but the question is very similar to this one and and the answer can be found here: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32613/splendor-can-i-use-gem-coins-instead-of-development-cards?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use your development card bonuses and not use tokens.

My answer to a similar question is [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/51383/how-can-you-ever-buy-a-development-card-with-14-tokens?rq=1) which covers the exact rules.